# Explicit formula for star product on the symmetric algebra of a Lie algebra via standard ordering

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, deformation-theory

There is a well known vector space isomorphism $\phi:\mathcal{S}(\frak{g})\rightarrow U(\frak{g})$ given by the symmetrization (or Weyl ordering), i.e.
$$ \phi(t_{i_1}\dots t_{i_k})=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}{t_{\sigma(i_1)}\dots t_{\sigma(i_k)}}, $$
where $\{t_1,\dotso,t_n\} $ is a basis for $\frak{g}$.
From $\phi$, one can define a star product on $\mathcal{S}(\frak{g})$ by the formula
$$a\ast b:=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\phi(b)). $$
I know there is an explicit formula for this product,
$$
    f(t)\ast g(t)=\exp\left(t_i m^i\left (\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)\right)f(u)g(v)|_{u,v=t}
$$
where $m^i$ are the components of
$$m(X,Y)=\log(e^X e^Y)-X-Y $$
with respect to the basis $\{t_i\}$.

I was interesting in knowing if there exists a similar formula for the star product in $\mathcal S({\frak{g})}$ defined by the standard ordering, i.e. the quantization map that sends a monomial in the basis elements of $\frak{g}$ into the corresponding ordered monomial in the PBW basis:

$$\psi(t_{i_1}\dots t_{i_k})=t_{i_1}\dots t_{i_k}, $$

for any choices of $i_1\leq i_2\leq\dotso\leq i_k$.

Comment: Yes, every ordering has its characteristic *-product, none of them as simple as the above. For simple cases, see this practical physics [booklet](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), and specifically equations (153), (154), (161),...(175) chapters 0.18 & 0.14. The normal ordering is intimately and historically related to the Weyl ordering, of course.